# how to prepare for reuse "KPDDropDownMenu" in tableviewcell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoapods

I am using KPDDropDownMenu inside tableview cell, when scroll the menu came with the objects from old reused cell.

My question is how to reuse in this situation

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let searchObject = searchObjects[indexPath.section]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: searchObject.viewIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    (cell as! CommonSearch).setup(withSearchObject: searchObject)
    (cell as? _DropDownTVC)?.dropDownOptions.optionsDidAppearedWithHeightClosure = {
        (optionsHeight) in
        self.searchObjects[indexPath.section].viewHeight += optionsHeight
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    return cell
}


func setup(withSearchObject searchObject: SearchObject) {
    searchkeyL.text = searchObject.searchKey
    dropDownOptions.items = searchObject.options
}
```

Comment: Can you share the link for that `KPDDropDownMenu`. Google doesn't return any result for it.

Comment: https://github.com/KrishnaPatell/KPDropMenu
here you are, I have solved the problem, Thank you